# How do I access the properties of UITextField's selectedTextRange UITextPosition objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, textselection, uitextposition

I'm trying to establish the start and end positions of a text selection of a `UITextField` instance, using its `selectedTextRange` property (as gained from the [`UITextInput` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput)). However, I have no idea how to access the properties of the `UITextPosition` objects that make up the `start` and `end` properties of `selectedTextRange`.

[Apple's docs on UITextPosition](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextposition) are woeful at this time, providing no methods or properties, though I know there are such properties in the object, because NSLogging one gives this:

```
<UITextPositionImpl: 0x6aaeb60>
<<WebVisiblePosition: 0x6aa40e0>(offset=5, context=([s|a], [u+0073|u+0061])>
```

In this example, the 'offset' is correct, and the context shows the characters either side of the selection point ('s' and 'a'), but I don't know how to access this nebulous `WebVisiblePosition` class. So, in short, is there a way of retrieving the details I want using `UITextPosition` objects from `UITextField`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, just after asking my question I found the answer, in this SO question: [UITextPosition in UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766077/uitextposition-in-uitextfield).

It seems that when used as part of `UITextField`, the `UITextPosition` objects are not meant to be tinkered with directly, but used to feed other methods. In this case, the method `offsetFromPosition:toPosition:`, along with the text field property `beginningOfDocument`, can be used to return an `NSInteger` of a selection index.